# Using the selector of a layout to change its child's properties

Tags: android, listview

By default, `ListView` changes background color to orange on being pressed and also the `TextColor` of `TextView` changes to white/black. By applying a selector on a `ListView` item we can set background color for pressed state but can we also define the `TextColor` for the `TextView` inside that item/layout within same selector? If so, then how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Amy88's answer resolved the problem, but doesn't specifically address changing a ViewGroup's child's properties.

Suppose you have a clickable `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` which should change color when pressed. The key is to use `android:duplicateParentState="true"` on the child views:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can specify the selector as in Amy88's answer.

Comment: This was what I have been looking for, without `android:duplicateParentState="true"` you cannot change all of the children of parent.

Answer (score 7):

If you are defining custom layout file for the ListAdapter, then set the text color of TextView in custom layout to an xml. This layout should be placed in a drawable resource folder (create a folder drawable and place the text_selector.xml in it).

text_selector.xml:

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
```

To set the text color use: **android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"**

The above sample xml will set the text color to white by default and will set the text color to black when the list item is focussed, selected or pressed.

Comment: im getting force close by applying following changes you told and the error here is you cannot use android:color attribute the only attribute you can use is android:drawable..........

Comment: Sam, I have edited the answer. Sorry that I had not mentioned how to use the xml in text color. Please try now.

Comment: it still not worked i realized that later and changed the same way you told

Comment: is thr anyway to change text shadow color dynamically like textcolor